# Injected interface in startup.cs class is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

net core exception handling in asp.net core 5 project but I want to save the exception in sql server database,but unfortunately when I inject that class have the insert method of exception to database it throw null reference exception for the injected interface into startup class:

```
private readonly IExceptionService exceptionService;
        public Startup(IExceptionService exceptionService)
        {
            this.exceptionService = exceptionService;
        }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        { app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
            {
                var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

                //  For Save Exception Log
                if (exceptionService is not null)
                {
                    exceptionService.AddException(exception);
                }
                // For Show Json Error in Resoponse
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new DTOResultObject(exception.Message));
            })); 
}
```

my startup class has another constructor at the first :

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }
```

could you help me to solve this problem? thanks, the null reference Exception Error is exactly for exceptionService in this line:

```
if (exceptionService is not null)
                {
                    exceptionService.AddException(exception);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register it in `ConfigureServices` method like below.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddSingleton<IExceptionService, Your_SQLExceptionService>();
        ...
    }
```

I also do some research, [find a useful repo for you](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/48903c3c31ac219f201c610e69872a4cc47b0f2e/MVCPro/Startup.cs#L69). It register `ExceptionService` like below

```
services.AddSingleton<IExceptionService, ExceptionService>();
```

**You can refer this to implement Your_SQLExceptionService like below**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVCPro.ActionFilters
{
    public interface IExceptionService
    {
        void Save(Exception ex);
    }

    public class ExceptionService : IExceptionService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public ExceptionService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public void Save(Exception ex)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MVCProContext>();
                _context.Add(new Book() { Title = ex.Message });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution got this error : String or binary data would be truncated, the statement has been terminated

Comment: @PEDRAMPOURHAKIM This error is given by the database, which means that there is a problem with your sql statement. So the problem with your current post should has been solved.

Comment: yeah, I deleted the limitions of the max length and  finally it worked fine, thanks a lot.